# Rails で既存のテーブルをモデル化したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails を今日から勉強し始めました

MySQL に memo というテーブルがあったときに
Rails で一覧画面と詳細、更新画面をつけて
web UIから更新できるようにしたいなと思ってます

```
rails g model memo
```

ってやるとなんかいろいろファイルが作られて

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

をやったときに

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):
```

というエラーが出るようになりました

エラーの意味がよくわからないのですがこれはどういうエラーなのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

未実行のマイグレーションが残ってるのでマイグレーションを実行してくださいっていうエラーです

普通ならそこに書いてる

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

を実行すれば解決すると思いますが

マイグレーションというのは db/migrate/ 以下にあるファイルのことで
Railsで使うモデルのテーブルを定義すれば勝手に管理してくれます

rails g model を行うと勝手にテンプレートを作ってくれるものなのですが
Rails 外や手動でテーブルを作成した場合はマイグレーションは不要なので消してしまっていいです

ただし Rails のデフォルトの複数形テーブル名、PK が id, timestamp カラムでないと
色々宣言が必要で慣れてないとハマりどころになるので
大きな理由がない限りはマイグレーションでテーブル作成することをお勧めします

Comment: テーブル作成までフレームワークがやってくれるのですね。知りませんでした。